# what is the proper way to import a csv in ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

There are soo many inherent problems with csv, 1) your columns can't have commas, so you have to encapsulate them with quotes "", and then once you encapsulate them with quotes, you have to already escape the quotes within a sentence by using \"

What is the easiest way to parse a csv file?  I reverted to doing semi-colon separated files but those are troublesome when working in excel, so now i'm back to csv files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html.

You can also look at http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

Comment: FasterCSV was renamed to CSV and replaced the original library as of Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Faster CSV](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv) from James Edward Gray II.

"FasterCSV is CSV, but faster, smaller, and cleaner."

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example using CSV in ruby:

```
class DataLoader

require 'csv'

def self.import_csv
    Dir.glob("/imports/*.csv").each do |csv_file|

        csv = CSV.open(csv_file, {:col_sep => ",", :headers => true, :return_headers => false, :quote_char => '"'})
        @data_table = csv.read

        @data_table.each do |data_row|
            field_one = data_row.first[0]
            field_two = data_row.first[1]
            #do some work
        end

end

end
```